# Excel split data into columns

Tags: excel

I have a column that each cell contains data of the following form:

```
 COLUMN 1
 a.jpg
 b.jpg
 c.jpg | d.jpg
 fd.jpg | dsf.jpg | ksk.jpg
 cccc.gif
 das.png
 ___dhi.jpg | bdi.png
```

and so on..

I want the column to split at the character |
so that the cell c.jpg | d.jpg --> becomes

```
   COLUMN 1          --->       COLUMN 1     COLUMN 2
  c.jpg | d.jpg      --->        c.jpg         d.jpg
```

Excel's text to columns cannot process this as i want it as the characetr | is not present for cell that do not have more than one filename.
How can I split the column 1 to to corresponding columns and of cource keep the cells that contain one filename as they are?

Comment: What's wrong with Text to Columns? It works for me. For the cells with only one name, they stay where they are.  Just choose a different destination for the split?

Comment: use the "Other:" check box http://www.exceldemy.com/how-to-split-text-into-multiple-cells-in-excel/

Comment: nope it doesnt work. If excel text to column does not find the "other" character, in my case the | character it stops from row 1 and does nothing. I use excel 10

Answer (score 0):

TLDR : Use notepad.

Long version.. copy the column 1 content to notepad. Then select all > copy > Paste Special (in excel) > set delimiter as "|" . Finish.

Hope it helps. (: